# In Rails, how do I validate a property on a model that belongs to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a book_review model which belongs_to a book model.

I need to validate that the book that the book_review belongs to has a model called author that is not empty, i.e. book_review belongs_to book, book.author is not empty

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You must make your question a bit clearer with code or some concrete examples.

Comment: Why does the book_review care that the book has an author? Usually the book model would verify this. Is there some case here where the book can be author less; until there is a review of the book?

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices.  Here are just a few:

```
delegate :author, to: :book
validates_presence_of :author
```

```
validate :book_has_author

private

def book_has_author
  book.author.present?
end
```

```
belongs_to :author, through: :book
validates_presence_of :author
```